# How to use orderBy with snapshotChanges() in Firestore Angular7

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore, angular7

I want to orderBy 'fullname' of 'employee' document in firestore using this code.

In service.ts

```
 getEmployees() {   
    return this.firestore.collection('employee').snapshotChanges();
  }
```

In Component.ts

```
  ngOnInit() {
            this.service.getEmployees().subscribe(actionArray => {
           let array = actionArray.map(item => {
             return {
               id: item.payload.doc.id,
               ...item.payload.doc.data()
             };

           });
         ....
}
```

I am beginner. What changes i need to make to this code so that i get desired output. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am assuming you are using Angular Firestore.
Try this:

> getEmployees() {
>           return this.firestore.collection('employee', ref => ref.orderBy('name','desc')).snapshotChanges();
>       }

Answer (score 0):

u can also do it this way, using multiple parameters

```
 getMyREQ(id){
    return this.adb.collection('bizREQUESTs', ref => ref.where('compid', '==', 
   id).orderBy('date','desc')).snapshotChanges();
  }
```